# I am not able to fill color for inverted graph and not able to customize y axis. Can anyone help me with this?

Tags: python, graph, xlsxwriter

I am facing below difficulties while plotting graph :

1 : not able to fill color for inverted graph.

2 : how can i customize y axis values. could not found any help from documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> not able to fill color for inverted graph.

In XlsxWriter charts you can use the `invert_if_negative` series property ([see docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-add-series)). For example:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Create a new Chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

# Write some data to add to plot on the chart.

worksheet.write_column('A1', [1, 3, -2, 1, -1])

# Configure the chart.
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5',
                  'invert_if_negative': True})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('C2', chart)


workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]

> how can i customize y axis values. could not found any help from documentation.

You can customize almost all properties of x and y axis values, or other properties. See the docs [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-set-x-axis) and [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_charts.html).

Comment: i hv already used invert_if_negative. But i need same colour as in positive graph. As it is coming as blank white.

Comment: If you need the same color for the negative values can’t you just leave out the invert_if_negative option? Maybe you should update the question to state exactly what what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you so much man... got the desired graph now. Just do not understand what is the use of invert_if_negative then?